# How to use SQL aggregate functions with an ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, aggregate-functions, adodb

In MS-Access 2019, I'd like to retrieve the number of rooms with 3 guests from `tblLink` like this:

```vb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, sSQL As String

sSQL = "SELECT Count(id) FROM tblLink WHERE bID=1 "
sSQL = sSQL & "GROUP BY rID HAVING Count(id)=3"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs

  Set .ActiveConnection = conn ' globally defined
  .CursorLocation = adUseClient
  .LockType = adLockReadOnly
  .Source = sSQL
  .Open    <---- Runtime Error

End With
```

... resulting in

> Runtime-error 3265: Item not found in this collection

When I paste the SQL into a query, I get the desired results.
I tried to single out the mistake by stripping down the SQL, but no success. I assume it is the `COUNT` causing trouble.

**How can I make this work in VBA with a `ADODB.Recordset`?**

**Edit**

`tblLink`:

```
id    bID    rID
-----------------
 1      3      2
 2      3      2
 3      3      2
 4      3      5
 5      3      5
 6      2      8
```

`bID`: booking id, `rID`: room id

booking `3` has 2 rooms, room `2` is occupied by 3 people, room `5` by 2 people.

**Edit**

`tblLink` is linked to `tblRoom` and `tblBooking`...

```
tblRoom                     tblBooking

id   name   type  etc.      id   start      end        status
long string string          long date       date       integer
----------------------      ---------------------------------
 2   A4       3B             3   1/28/2020  1/30/2020       1 
 5   B1       2B             2   1/24/2020  1/28/2020       1
 8   B4       1B


 tblRoom.id ---- tblLink.rID
                 tblLink.bID ---- tblBooking.id
```

**Edit**

`conn` is defined in a global module, and it is working fine:

```vb
Dim m_conn As ADODB.Connection

Public Function conn() As ADODB.Connection

  If m_conn Is Nothing Then Set m_conn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
  Set conn = m_conn

End Function
```

Comment: Why use ADODB? DAO is simpler. What will you do with recordset once it is open? Should probably provide an alias field name for Count() calculation. What is bID and why this filter? Edit question to show sample source data.

Comment: Count(*) itself is not issue, works for me with: `rs.Open "SELECT Count(*) AS C FROM Rates", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic`

Comment: @June7 I read the results and display them in a textfield. See my edit. I use `ADODB` because I like it.

Comment: I tested your code syntax (only with `.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection`) and it works. Cannot replicate issue. `Set` was not needed for connection property but also worked with it.

Comment: If you want to group by `rID` have you tried including that column in your query?

Comment: I assume `tblLink` is a linked table. Support for linked tables over ADO is limited and context-dependent. Please provide a full [mre]

Comment: @TimWilliams no difference, still runtime-error coming up

Comment: ... But is it linked? And if so, what's the source? Provide the full table definition.

Comment: @ErikA see my edit...

Comment: deleted all relationships between tables --> problem persists @ErikA